# pyplot catch windows 10 close windows event

Tags: python, matplotlib

how can I catch a close event from the windows close button in pyplot? the app is totally simple, but I want to stop plotting when the windows closer is clicked.

```
plt.axis([0, 100, 0, 255, -5, 5])
plt.ion()
plt.show()

mainloop:
   plt.plot (whatever)
```

Comment: there is a `"close_event"` you can connect to a callback that would set the condition of the loop such that it stops.

Comment: I know, that what i did with a close button in the app, but how to catch the windows close?

Comment: The close event will trigger on any type of closing, whether it's through the close button (pressing "q"), the red x on the top right, calling `plt.close()`, doesn't matter.

Comment: oh yes, your are right, how can move the plot like printing on a paper roll?